# Reducing power consumption on a low-load server running WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp

I am using a quad-core windows XP based Dell Machine machine in my office as a server for an application that I am developing and for occasional work with remote desktop connection.

The machine is typically under very light load, running a MySQL server with few connections and a few Java processes that make a database connection every few minutes.

When I log into it or when the occasional user submits a request to the server, there is a need for more processing power.

Is there some way to get it to consume less power but still continue running 24x7? On my Mac Pro, for example, I can (manually) shut down a few CPUs which I've noticed affects power consumption. What are my options on XP?

I realize that this is not directly a programming question, but I'm sure somebody here has a computer running on a similar usage profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good first step is to use the Power tool in Control Panel (powercfg.cpl) to make a custom profile that will power down screen, disks, etc. after a reasonable idle period. Don't make periods too short or re-powering up the device may waste more power than was saved by turning it off; especially important for hard disks.

Disable any services (and possibly devices too) that are not required in your configuration (e.g. Content Indexer, WebClient).

Also make sure that your BIOS settings allow your processor clock to go as slow as possible. Some motherboard device drivers take their settings from the BIOS. Turn off any overclocking software and reset those settings to "auto" or "default".

Use devmgmt.msc check the power settings for each device driver. Some drivers are dumb and don't allow controlling the power to their devices but most USB hosts/hubs do.

Comment: I am not sure turning of the disk would work since I am accessing the database every few minutes... Screen is alreayd off when I am not there.

Is there a way to shut down CPUs?

I'll look at the power options.

Comment: If the database work is read-only select queries then the disk often doesn't need to spin up if the data is already in a memory cache. Separating the OS, DB data and DB log onto 3 separate drives may allow just one to power up while the others sleep.

Comment: I don't think Windows has support for turning off a particular core. But the motherboard/BIOS stuff I mentioned may put them all into a low power state - most CPUs spend a lot of the time in a halt state anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are some motherboards from various manufacturers that provide power management tools that can be used from within windows.  Perhaps this would be the best place to start.  Post more about your system specs and maybe I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late for this post, but hopefully it helps someone at somepoint in the future...

In response to turning off cores in XP to conserve power, there is a built-in solution from MS. Go to Start, Run and then type msconfig and hit enter.  After the system configuration utility window opens, click on the BOOT.INI tab and click the Advanced Options button.  You can effectively limit the amount of active cores by checking the box next to "/NUMPROC=" and entering a number in the field to the right.  The number that you enter will be the new number of active cores on your processor (after a reboot of course...). Set it to whatever you like and reboot the PC.  After the reboot open up task manager and under the Performance tab you should see fewer graphs on the CPU Usage History window (each window represents an active core. check this before you make the initial change and it will show all cores that your system is using. check task manager (after you make the change in msconfig and reboot the PC) again to verify that the change you made in msconfig has taken effect.

Again, I know this is an old post but I figured that someone eventually will come looking at this page and hopefully it will be of some service to them.